# Better way to extract a substring in bash

Tags: linux, bash, regex

I have a list of `mp3` files named like so:

```
$artist/$album ($year)/$tracknum $title.mp3
```

Many of these tracks have incorrect or missing tags, which I am correcting through the use of [`id3v2`](http://id3v2.sourceforge.net/) and regex because the file names are all correct. Here is an example of how I'm setting titles:

```
for mp3 in *.mp3; do id3v2 -t "$(echo $mp3 | cut -d. -f1 | cut -d\  -f2-)" "$mp3"; done
```

(Note: quotes are there because the titles often have spaces, which causes bash to complain unless spaces are used)

My question is this: is there a better way to extract a specific substring from these files? In the case of the titles, I can't use `grep -o` without also matching `$tracknum` because many tracks have numbers and spaces in the titles (meaning that I'd need `"([0-9a-zA-Z ]+)"` for my pattern, which matches the entire filename before the `.mp3`).

I'm almost certain that there is a much better way to do this. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the title (and, in case it's useful, the tracknum), you should be able to do it like this:

```
read -r tracknum title <<<$(basename "$mp3" .mp3)
```

For the other bits, I'd start by splitting the filename by `/` to isolate the parts. For example:

```
album_year=$(cut -d/ -f2 <<<"$mp3")
album=${album%\ (*)}
year=${album_year:-5:4}
```

The last one is dependent on the year actually being present and four digits long; if that's not guaranteed then you could do it using a more clumsy expression:

```
year=${album_year:$((${#album}+2)):$((${#album_year}-${#album}-3}
```

Also, if you don't know how deep in the path the `album_year` part is, you can extract the second last segment (i.e. the immediate directory of the file) with:

```
album_year=$(basename "$(dirname "$mp3")")
```

Or, you can split the entire path into an array:

```
IFS=/ read -ra segments <<<"$mp3"
album_year=${segments[-2]}
```

Comment: I had to reverse the path string (it's the complete path from `/`) before passing it to cut, but this was overall very helpful.

Comment: @J.DavidSmith: You could have just adjusted the -f2 to the actual depth :) I added another way to get the second last component of a filepath.

Comment: If I could upvote your answer again I would.